# Get visible rows in PrimeFaces DataTable

Tags: java, jsf, primefaces, datatable

I'm looking for a way to get a list with all rows that are currently visible in my PrimeFaces DataTable (sth. like `List getVisibleRows()`). Filters set by a user have to be take into account as well.

Has anyone an idea?

Comment: Are you looking to get this for an unfiltered table? Or after a table has been filtered?

Comment: I need it for both cases, regardless of the table has been filtered or not.